# What is the difference between bidirectional RNN and bidirectional LSTM?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, bidirectional

Recently I started with LSTM but when I came to bidirectional I confused with bidirectional RNN and bidirectional LSTM ! are they same ?
what is bidirectional encoding layer?

Comment: They are different for the implementation of RNN (as in simple RNN) vs LSTM, but same in terms of bidirectionality. I have also found that "Schuster, M. and Paliwal, K. K. (1997). Bidirectional recurrent neural networks. IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing, 45, 2673–2681" is the first paper on Bi-RNN. However, not sure how Bi-LSTM has started - can trace this to be the earliest - "Graves, A. and Schmidhuber, J. (2005). Framewise phoneme classification with bidirectional LSTM and other neural network architectures. Neural Networks, 18(5-6), 602–610."

Answer (score 1):

Let's separate two concepts here.

The term bidirectional means that you'll run your input in two direction (from past to future and from future to past).

The second part is LSTM or RNN which are the core. You can learn more in details about RNN and LSTM here [RNN and LSTM](https://towardsdatascience.com/recurrent-neural-networks-and-lstm-4b601dd822a5)